# Swagger Operation_ID Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I actually want to display the operation_Id field that is provided by JSON in my Swagger-UI and for this particular case we are using customize Swagger-ui.html file and below are the approaches I have Used.

- set displayOperationId: true in swagger-ui.html
- declare bean for UI coonfiguration in swagger config java file

  ```
  @Bean
  UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder() 
        .deepLinking(true)
        .displayOperationId(true)
        .defaultModelsExpandDepth(1)
        .defaultModelExpandDepth(1)
        .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.EXAMPLE)
        .displayRequestDuration(false)
        .docExpansion(DocExpansion.NONE)
        .filter(false)
        .maxDisplayedTags(null)
        .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.ALPHA)
        .showExtensions(true)
        .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA)
        .validatorUrl(null)
        .build();
  }
  ```

  above bean, the approach is working fine for default swagger-UI.html, but not working on custom swagger

any help related to this is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working on custom swagger' it won't load the configuration?

Comment: It not working in my case as I enable operation_id: true, still I am not able to see it in my UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

closing as there is no further investigation on same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).